# Update Firebase user profile

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to update my app, so that users can create profiles with more than just an email and password. But I keep on getting different errors for each method i try.
I want to start only with the ability to register a username

Heres my code regarding the registering methods:

```
import {Text, TextInput, View, Image, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import { authentication} from '../firebase-config';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth';
import { useTailwind } from 'tailwind-rn/dist';

const Registration = ({navigation}) => {
    const [email, setemail] = useState('')
    const [password, setpassword] = useState('')
    const [username, setusername] = useState('')

    const tailwind = useTailwind();

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = authentication.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                navigation.navigate("onboarding")
            }
        })  
        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    const Register = () =>{
    
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(authentication, email, password)
        .then(authentication, userCredentials => {
            return userCredentials.user.updateProfile({
                displayName: username,
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                alert('That email address is already in use!');
            }
        
            if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                alert('That email address is invalid!');
            }
        
            console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

I get errors as such:

> [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userCredentials.user.updateProfile')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import `updateProfile` and `getAuth` from `firebase/auth`.

Then initialize Firebase Authentication using `getAuth()`.

```js
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

const Register = () => {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredentials) => {
      updateProfile(user, {
        displayName: username,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```